# Remove class onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons, one that adds a product to my cart and the other one that deletes a product from my cart. Now when you click on `add product` a class is added to the add button `blur`. Using this code:

```
function showDel($this) {
  var dataProduct = $this.attr("data-product");
    $(".delete-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']").show();
    $(".add-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']").addClass( "blur");
}
```

This also makes the button `delete-product` appear. I would like to remove the class `blur` when the delete-product button is pressed.

I have a little peace of code that hides the `delete-product` button. I would like to use that to remove the class `blur` from the `add-product` button.

```
function hideDel($this) {
  $this.hide();
}
```

I tried adding the code below to the `hideDel` function, but that doesn't work because you don't click on the `add-product` button.

`$(".add-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']").removeClass( "blur" );`

This also doesn't work.

```
$('.delete-product').click(function() {
  $(".add-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']").removeClass( "blur" );
});
```

This works, but it then removes the class from all the buttons:

```
$('.delete-product').click(function() {
    $(".add-product").removeClass( "blur" );
});
```

How can I tell the `delete-product` button to remove the class `blur` from `.add-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']` when `delete-product` is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function hideDel($this) {
    var dataProduct = $this.attr("data-product");
    $this.hide();
    $(".add-product[data-product='" + dataProduct + "']").removeClass("blur");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the var. This works perfect! Thanks!